# Compare all data between 2 sheets, print header and key on new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, nested-loops

Goal: 
Find primary key match from NuMAP on DL sheet. If not found, print primary key from NuMAP Column A onto error sheet. If it is found, loop through all cells in that row, comparing data between 2 sheet(DL, NuMAP). If data on NuMAP sheet does not equal data on DL sheet for given (key,column) than print the column and key on new sheet.

Data Structure:
There is a primary key in the first column of both sheets. The columns are ordered the same between the 2 sheets, but the rows are not. There could be a different number of rows between sheets.

ISSUE: the base of the code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664381/compare-rows-and-cells-within-those-rows-on-two-spreadsheets-using-vba-in-exce). It loops the through the sheets properly but I am not sure how to change it to copy the header and key and put that on a new sheet. I have put in my best guess as to how to do it but would love some help.

```
Sub DetectChanges()
    Dim DL As Worksheet, NuMAP As Worksheet '<-- explicitly declare each variable type
    Dim DLData, ErrorShtrng As Range, f As Range, cell As Range
    Dim icol, lastrow As Long
    Dim ErrorSht

    Set DL = Worksheets("Account_Master_DL").columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- set a range with DL cells containing data
    Set ErrorSht = Worksheets("Acct_master_Error")
    lastrow = ErrorSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ErrorShtrng = ErrorSht.Range("A" & lastrow)


    With Worksheets("Account_Master_NuMAP") '<--| reference NuMAP
        For Each cell In Intersect(.UsedRange, .columns(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-_| loop through its column "A" non blank cells
            Set f = DLData.Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<--| search for current cell value in DL data
            If f Is Nothing Then '<--| if not found then...
                Intersect(cell.EntireRow, .UsedRange).Address.Copy ErrorShtrng '<--| copy primary key from column A into Errorsht Col A next open row, put "All" in Col B
            Else
                For icol = 1 To .Range(cell, .Cells(cell.Row, .columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).columns.Count - 1 '<--| loop through NuMAP current cell row
                    If f.Offset(, icol) <> cell.Offset(, icol) Then '<--| if it doesn't match corresponding cell in DL
                        cell.Offset(, icol).Copy ErrorShtrng '<--| copy primary key in Column A, Header of column to ErrorSht columns A, B

                    End If
                Next icol
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set f = DLData.Find(...)` what is DLData here?

Comment: `Intersect(cell.EntireRow, .UsedRange).Address.Copy ErrorShtrng` drop the `Address` here and then you need to move `ErrorShtrng` down one row for the next copy...

Comment: Thanks Tim, in the original script(see link) it was ws1data. I just renamed it DLData to better represent my sheets. It seems like it is functioning as the range in the Dl sheet that contains the primary keys which the NuMAP Data is searching across for a common value.

Comment: But you need to set it to something

Comment: After looking at it again, i am not sure what DLData is or how it works without being defined. In the first insatnce it is referenced in the first IF it is searching the primary keys in DL Data but in the second IF function it represents whatever cell in DL that is being compared to the Numap Data.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Find, but after a bit of research it looks like DLData essentially taking over for the Cell object and essentially putting parameters for what should be looked for in the Cell. See DLData.Find(what:=cell.Value...)

Comment: @user3598756 can you offer any assistance here?

Answer (score 0):

Compiled but not tested:

```
Sub DetectChanges()

    Dim ErrorShtrng As Range, f As Range, cell As Range, icol As Long
    Dim wsError As Worksheet, wsDL As Worksheet, wsNuMAP As Worksheet

    Set wsError = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Acct_master_Error")
    Set wsDL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Account_Master_DL")
    Set wsNuMAP = Worksheets("Account_Master_NuMAP")

    Set ErrorShtrng = wsError.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) '<< next empty row

    With wsNuMAP
        For Each cell In Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            Set f = wsDL.Columns(1).Find(what:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If f Is Nothing Then
                Intersect(cell.EntireRow, .UsedRange).Copy ErrorShtrng
                Set ErrorShtrng = ErrorShtrng.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
            Else
                For icol = 1 To .Range(cell, .Cells(cell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Columns.Count - 1
                    If f.Offset(, icol) <> cell.Offset(, icol) Then
                        ErrorShtrng.Value = cell.Value
                        ErrorShtrng.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(, icol).EntireColumn.Cells(2).Value 'if headers in row2
                        Set ErrorShtrng = ErrorShtrng.Offset(1, 0)
                    End If
                Next icol
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```